# How to remove these marks or stains on the coating caused by fungus?

Tags: old-lenses, cleaning, fungus, optical-coating

I have a acquired a mint(almost) Super-Multi-Coated Takumar 135mm f3.5, from the outside the lens body has no signs of usage, no paint chips or stains on the barrel but looking at the optics it has a large amount of fungus living on all the 4 elements of the lens. So I thought that this lens was never used and only stored in a very bad way. I dismantled the lens to try to clean each element hoping that each element would not etched from the fungus, I use a 6% hydrogen peroxide with q-tips and successfully removes them and a final wash of dish soap to remove any residues left. Upon inspecting each lens I notice each infected lens have these marks or stains on the surface of the lens. It's not clear to me if it etched the glass or are these marks can be removed without polishing? I forgot to take a photo before I cleaned the lens elements but you can see the traces it left.
[image: Last rear element]

[image: Third element from the front]

[image: Second element from the front]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to remove something that isn't there. The fungus has etched away part of the coating or even the glass itself. It's gone.